# How To Draw A String Variable with g.drawString();?

Tags: java

I've been trying to draw a String variable from another class with the g.drawString(); method. Here is my code:

```
g2.drawString(lang.menu[i], MainPanel.SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, MainPanel.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 + i * 22);
```

I have tried having the Lang.menu[] String static and not static but it doesn't seem to effect it at all. Any help?

Lang.menu[]:

```
public String[] menu;{
    if(Main.langPicked == 1){
        menu[0] = "Singleplayer";
        menu[1] = "Multiplayer";
        menu[2] = "Options";
        menu[3] = "Exit Game";
    }else if(Main.langPicked == 2){
        menu[0] = "Solo";
        menu[1] = "Multijoueur";
        menu[2] = "Options";
        menu[3] = "Quitter Le Jeu";
    }else if(Main.langPicked == 3){
        menu[0] = "Singleplayer";
        menu[1] = "Multiplayer";
        menu[2] = "Opties";
        menu[3] = "Verlaat Het Spel";
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `lang.menu[i]` contain? Did you try to print it?

Comment: Can you provide a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: You shouldn't be relying on "magic" numbers like `MainPanel.SCREEN_WIDTH` but should be relying on the actual size of the component

Comment: @Zhedar added the lang.menu[] to the main post. I tried to print it and it returned another error.

Comment: What error? As it stands, the questions doesn't have sufficient information to diagnose the problem in order to provide a possible solution...not to mention the fact that the declaration of the `menu` can't possible compile...

Comment: You should definitely read the trail on [Internationalization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/intro/index.html) in [The Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html). What you are doing to display translated strings is horrible. Also, use [`enum` types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) instead of magic numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this then calling `fillMenu()`

```
public String[] menu;

public void fillMenu()
{
    menu = new String[4];

    if(Main.langPicked == 1) {
        menu[0] = "Singleplayer";
        menu[1] = "Multiplayer";
        menu[2] = "Options";
        menu[3] = "Exit Game";
    } 
    else if(Main.langPicked == 2) {
        menu[0] = "Solo";
        menu[1] = "Multijoueur";
        menu[2] = "Options";
        menu[3] = "Quitter Le Jeu";
    } 
    else if(Main.langPicked == 3) {
        menu[0] = "Singleplayer";
        menu[1] = "Multiplayer";
        menu[2] = "Opties";
        menu[3] = "Verlaat Het Spel";
    }
}
```